# GlassFish 4.1 startup warnings: javax.ejb.PostActivate & javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, weld, glassfish-4.1

Whenever I startup GlassFish 4.1, I get the following two warnings in my GlassFish log:

```
WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled

WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
```

Both of the referenced classes are, however, in the `glassfish/modules/javax.ejb-api.jar`.

Is there any way to fix / prevent these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

I think that warnings you can ignore. I had never issues with that and they exists not only for the last version. And its only a warning :)

But if you want use a more maintained glassfish, so have a look here:
[glassfish replacement with a few bugfixes](http://www.payara.fish)